# centOs 7 can't find python3-PyYAML and python3-gobject while searching for dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos, pyyaml, gobject

trying to install lutris on centOs 7
it can't find python3-gobject and python3-PyYAML
But i have installed this for every python i have = )

i tried:
yum install PyYAML
            python3-PyYAML
pip install, pip3 install, etc

but it still complains for this dependency 
I guess i need to set it visible somehow but have no ideas how

Please help = )

```
Error: Package: lutris-0.4.19-4.1.noarch (/lutris-0.4.19-4.1.noarch)
       Requires: python3-gobject
Error: Package: lutris-0.4.19-4.1.noarch (/lutris-0.4.19-4.1.noarch)
       Requires: python3-PyYAML
```

I tried to list all PyYAML but it only see it for python2.7

```
$ rpm -ql PyYAML

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyYAML-3.10-py2.7.egg-info
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/_yaml.so
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/__init__.pyc
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/__init__.pyo
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/composer.py
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/composer.pyc
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/composer.pyo
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/constructor.pyc
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/constructor.pyo
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/cyaml.py
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/cyaml.pyc
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/cyaml.pyo
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/dumper.py
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/dumper.pyc
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/dumper.pyo
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/emitter.py
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/emitter.pyc
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/emitter.pyo
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/error.py
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/error.pyc
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/error.pyo
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/events.py
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/events.pyc
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/events.pyo
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/loader.py
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/loader.pyc
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/loader.pyo
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/nodes.py
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/nodes.pyc
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/nodes.pyo
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/parser.py
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/parser.pyc
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/parser.pyo
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/reader.py
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/reader.pyc
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/reader.pyo
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/representer.py
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/representer.pyc
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/representer.pyo
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/resolver.py
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/resolver.pyc
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/resolver.pyo
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/scanner.pyc
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/scanner.pyo
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/serializer.py
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/serializer.pyc
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/serializer.pyo
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/tokens.py
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/tokens.pyc
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/tokens.pyo
/usr/share/doc/PyYAML-3.10
/usr/share/doc/PyYAML-3.10/CHANGES
/usr/share/doc/PyYAML-3.10/LICENSE
/usr/share/doc/PyYAML-3.10/PKG-INFO
/usr/share/doc/PyYAML-3.10/README
/usr/share/doc/PyYAML-3.10/examples
/usr/share/doc/PyYAML-3.10/examples/pygments-lexer
/usr/share/doc/PyYAML-3.10/examples/pygments-lexer/example.yaml
/usr/share/doc/PyYAML-3.10/examples/pygments-lexer/yaml.py
/usr/share/doc/PyYAML-3.10/examples/yaml-highlight
/usr/share/doc/PyYAML-3.10/examples/yaml-highlight/yaml_hl.cfg
/usr/share/doc/PyYAML-3.10/examples/yaml-highlight/yaml_hl.py
```

Answer (score 2):

I also tried lutris on Cent OS 7.6

python 3.6 -> `sudo yum  install python36`

Python 3.6 PyYAML and Gobject are actually not available in 7 release, it will be available on CentOS 8.0 it will be based on fedora 28. But it will release somewhere at the end of january 2019. So try installing manually from

https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=python3-PyYAML
https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=python3-gobject

make sure you download one from fedora not from suse or other rpms. 
python 3.6 install it from official repos. it should work last time I was able to run successfully :)

Answer (score 0):

It's simple and you can try by the following steps:

> Create repo file and add the bellow lines
>
> `sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/pyYAML.repo`

```
[pyYAML]
name=python3.6-pyYAML
baseurl=https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

> then Update repo and install

```
sudo yum update 
sudo yum install python36-PyYAML
```

> In case you have not python3.6 in your machine then install

```
sudo yum install python-devel python36
```